# Interpretation of cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I think I understand this problem but I feel like I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out what it is.
I am given the probability density function $f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} 6x(1-x) & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 & aoc
\end{matrix} \right.$ and I have to find a number $m$ so that $P(X<m) = 2P(X>m)$.

I found the cumulative distribution function $F(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} 0 & -\infty < x \leq 0 \\
3x^{2}-2x^{3} & 0 < x \leq 1\\
1 & 1 < x < \infty
\end{matrix} \right.$, and from $P(X<m) = 2P(X>m)$ I figured that I have to find a number $m$ so that $F(m) = 2(1-F(m))$. From that I find that $F(m) = \frac{2}{3}$, but when I substitute $F(m)$ I get $3m^{2} - 2m^{3} = \frac{2}{3}$. Solving for $m$ in that equation I can only find irrational results and I don't think that's right. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there some reason you think the result can't be irrational?

Comment: In this particular course we haven't studied numerical methods for equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(X<m) + P(X>m) = 1$ (these two events partition the sample space and we see that $X$ is continuous), know that $P(X<m)=\frac23$.

Your CDF is correct. There is nothing significant about the fact that $m$ is irrational. $3m^2-2m^3=\frac23$ is more complex than $3m^2=\frac23 \implies m = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ which is also irrational. So there is no reason to believe the $m$ must be rational.

In fact, by the [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), any rational roots to $3m^2-2m^3 =-2m^3 + 3m^2 =\frac23$ must be of the form $\frac{3k}{-2r}\;\;k\in \mathbb{Z}: 3k,-2r\text{ relatively prime }$

Since $m \in [0,1]$, we need $r<0,k>0$. The possible numerators are $\pm 1, \pm 2$, possible denominators are $\pm 1, \pm 3$ so we have possible (positive) rational solutions:

$$2, 1,\frac23, \frac13$$

Checking each of these we get:$-4,1,\frac{36}{27}-\frac{16}{27} = 20/27, \frac{9}{27} - \frac{2}{27}=\frac{7}{27}$

None of these equal $\frac23$ so actually all solutions will be irrational, as you have found.